# How can I convert List<object> to Hashtable in C#?

Tags: c#, list, hashtable

I have a list of objects, each containing an Id, Code and Description.

I need to convert this list into a Hashtable, using **Description** as the key and **Id** as the value.

This is so the Hashtable can then be serialised to JSON.

Is there a way to convert from List<Object> to Hashtable without writing a loop to go through each item in the list?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Let's assume that your List contains objects of type Foo (with an int Id and a string Description).

You can use Linq to turn that list into a Dictionary like this:

```
var dict = myList.Cast<Foo>().ToDictionary(o => o.Description, o => o.Id);
```

Comment: That example is spot on. Linq keeps solving problems left, right and centre.

Comment: Great stuff! This is almost identical to what I had just written using the examples from Frank's link. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to Linq, you can use the [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
theList.ForEach(delegate(theObject obj) { dic.Add(obj.Id, obj.Description); });
```

Comment: The parallel version is very dangerous; you are assuming that the dictionary is going to be thread-safe, which it is documented as *not* being. Now, if there were a PFX version of ToDictionary, then that might be different - but .Add(...) - risky ;-p

Comment: How very true! :) 
I've removed that implementation from my entry.

Comment: Very good answer. This is a testimonial. http://diditwith.net/2006/10/05/PerformanceOfForeachVsListForEach.aspx

Comment: JMSA: Cool, always interesting to see number like these. Won't really have a major impact on app perf., but still cool :)

Answer (score -1):

Also look at the `System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>`.  It seems like a better match for what you want to do.