# Converting var data to hashtable

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is it possible to convert a var data to hashtable?

```
Hashtable hsTest = new Hashtable();
        var oFeat = (from t in db.test
                     where t.Product_ID == iProductID
                     select t);
```

Comment: Yes. Check out the ToDictionary() method here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166174/how-can-i-convert-listobject-to-hashtable-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to use Product_ID as key in the hashtable and something like Product_Name as value. You could do it like this:

```
Hashtable hsTest = new Hashtable ();
var oFeat = (from t in db.test
             where t.Product_ID == iProductID
             select t);
foreach (var product in oFeat) {
    hsTest[product.Product_ID] = product.Product_Name;
}
```

Comment: I have a textbox and a button. in buttton click the textbox entry should be there in gridview. But i want that without a DB entry. For that i was trying with hashtable. Can anyone please tel me how to do that?