# C# Converting a list<model> to a dictionary<enum, List<model>> based on enum property in the models?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

Not to be confused with: [How can I convert List to Hashtable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166174/how-can-i-convert-listobject-to-hashtable-in-c)

I have a list of Models that I want to organize into a hashtable with the enums as the key, and the list of Models (that have the enum's value) as the value.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    Blue,
    Green
}

public class MyModel
{
    public MyModel(MyEnum myEnum, string foo, int bar)
    {
        this.MyEnum = myEnum;
        this.Foo = foo;
        this.Bar = bar;
    }

    public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

List<MyModel> models = new List<MyModel>();

models.Add(new MyModel(MyEnum.Blue, "How", 1));
models.Add(new MyModel(MyEnum.Green, "Now", 2));
models.Add(new MyModel(MyEnum.Blue, "Brown", 3));
models.Add(new MyModel(MyEnum.Green, "Cow", 4));
```

What is the easiest way to convert the list into a hash table that would look like this (Forgive the json):

```
{ 
   Blue:
   [
      { Blue, "How", 1 },
      { Blue, "Brown", 3 }
   ],
   Green:
   [
      { Green, "Now", 2 },
      { Green, "Cow", 4 }
   ]
}
```

When I do something like this:

```
var taskTable = tasks.Cast<TaskModel>().ToDictionary(o => o.Task); (Where Task is the Enum)
```

I get this exception: "An item with the same key has already been added."

One liners with Lambda or Linq are appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me like you could do with a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx):

```
var lookup = models.ToLookup(o => o.Task);
```

Or if you really want the `Dictionary<MyEnum, List<TaskModel>>`:

```
var dictionary = models.GroupBy(o => o.Task)
                       .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Comment: Perfect! I do love 1-line elegant solutions!

Comment: @Levitikon: And LINQ gives so many of them... if I could have a man-crush on a technology, LINQ would be it... followed by LINQ to XML.

Comment: @JonSkeet: you're so right! Linq was one of the best inventions MS ever made. It makes coding (in many cases) more readable. But like always in life: you can't get the good without the worse - sometimes you can make statements haaaaard to read! ;-)

Comment: `Lookup`s are great because they also indicate the intent, and are optimized for this functionality.